# Выделение активного пункта меню на php

Tags: php, css

Привет, не могу разобраться, как можно выделить активный пункт меню.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="<?=PATH?>">Главная</a></li>
         <?php if($pages): ?>
               <?php foreach($pages as $item): ?>
                       <li><a href="?view=page&amp;page_id=  <?=$item['page_id']?>"><?=$item['title']?></a></li>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ух-х, ну на PHP это никто не делает, обычно это работа "фронтэнда". В данном случае это можно "набыд***одить" следующим образом. Пишите CSS класс, например, active, который должен менять выбранный элемент (как выделенный). Далее получаете индикатор текущего `page_id`, и применяем для него класс active:

```
<li <?= if($_GET['page_id']==$item['page_id']) echo ='class="active"'; ?>><a href="?view=page&amp;page_id=<?=$item['page_id']?>"><?=$item['title']?></a></li>
```

Но уж очень это по-страшному выглядит, используйте в самом крайнем случае, если нет возможности изучить JS, jquery, прочее.

Comment: а можно про фронтенд подробнее, как сделать неглючный роутинг по страницам на чистом JS без использования всяких аргуляров или бэкбонов :)

Comment: Не самый лучший пример, но все же. http://likbezz.ru/publ/ucoz/scripts/how_can_i_make_an_active_link_javascript_css/29-1-0-53

Answer (score 1):

Обычно я делаю конструкцию, в которой сравнивается текущий урл страницы с ссылкой на эту страницу, если делать на чистом php, то в вашем случае можно вот так:

```
<?php 
    $active = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '?view=page&amp;page_id='.$item['page_id']) ? ' class="active"' : '';
    foreach($pages as $item) {
       echo '<li'.$active.'>';
       echo '<a href="?view=page&amp;page_id='.$item['page_id'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a>';
       echo '</li>';
    }
 ?>
```

И соотвественно в css добавляете:

```
.active a {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: @MasterAlex, Добрый день, в первой строчке подсвечивает красным, где-то ошибка.

Comment: @Alextrue, да-да, опечатался и тернарный оператор неправильно написал, теперь всё должно работать. :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, что-то не работает. ( Ошибок нет, но стиль не применяется.

Comment: @MasterAlex, что-то не работает.